# Java ClassNotFoundException Drivers not loading

Tags: java, exception, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to connect to a database.
I tried many drivers but every time it throws an exception.
I am not working on any project. Just the following code and compiling through command line using javac.

Here is code

```
// File JdbcEx.java
//step 1: import package
import java.sql.*;

public class JdbcEx {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
 //Step 2: load driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//Step 3: define the connection URL
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:personDSN";
//Step 4: establish the connection
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
//Step 5: create Statement
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
//Step 6: preapare & execute the query
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Person";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
   //Step 7: process the results
        while (rs.next()) {
 // The row name is "name" in database "PersonInfo,
 // hence specified in the getString() method.
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String add = rs.getString("address");
            String pNum = rs.getString("phoneNum");
            System.out.println(name + " " + add + " " + pNum);
        }
   //Step 8: close the connection
         con.close();
    } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
        System.out.println(sqlEx);
    }
} // end main
} // end class
```

It shows the following exception on runtime every time.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver this changes with driver.

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: java JdbcEx       in the command line

Comment: You have to add your jar with the driver to the classpath.

Comment: using JDK 15    and   JRE 1.8.0_261

Comment: How to add jars while writing code in text editor..   Its easy to add in maven or gradle but I am not using any build envirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling Java program with javac succeeds, but NoClassDefFoundError on run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233679/compiling-java-program-with-javac-succeeds-but-noclassdeffounderror-on-run)

Comment: @UsmanKhan Just use the commandline options of `java`: `--class-path`

Comment: Loading the MySQL driver for URLs that have the prefix `jdbc:odbc:` makes no sense. Also note that the JdbcOdbc driver was removed from Java in Java 8, so unless you have a third-party driver that supports the `jdbc:odbc:` URL prefix, then you won't be able to connect using ODBC anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the jar with the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in the classpath.
Try running with:

```
java --class-path=.;nameOfYourJarWithTheClassInIt.jar JdbcEx
```

Comment: Does this help you:https://stackoverflow.com/q/5616898/13912132

Comment: Thanks it worked.